# How did Rammus get this fast?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was watching [this clip](https://youtu.be/wgNMe25bmhM?t=6) and clearly see Rammus' movement speed increase to an ungodly figure of over 2200.

He activated Yommu's, Righteous Glory, Powerball and was under the influence of Homeguard. Even so, I thought there was a cap on movement speed where the effectiveness of multipliers were exponentially reduced the faster you go.

So how was Rammus able to move this insanely fast?

Comment: There is no limit to [movement speed](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Movement_speed). I would answer but I don't exactly understand how all the formulas work. Basically it is soft capped at 490 and then everything after seems to be reduced by 50%.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The last soft cap for movement speed is at 490 u/s as [@VanBuzzKill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317655/how-did-rammus-get-this-fast#comment451905_317655) mentioned in his comment.

This means while the movement speed gained from spell is heavily reduced, it is still possible to achieve [insanely high speed numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljtt_dYIMTc).

In your video Rammus got a Righteous Glory, a Dead Man's plate, a Yomuu's, Boots of Swiftness and a Runic Echoes enchantment. In addition to that he got help from Zilean (99% MS) and Homeguard (150% MS).

The most important thing about reaching this much MS without much effort is Rammus's Q which grants him an additional **275% MS increase that works multiplicatively** (most percentage increases for movement speed work additively, this one doesn't). This is the main reason why it's so easy to reach high speeds with Rammus in a normal game.

Comment: That's the bit I was missing, the multiplicative multiplier on his Q. I didn't even see the Zilean.